# PHP IMAP : How to block fetching of images when retrieving emails from gmail using IMAP and PHP

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I'm retrieving body text of emails from my Gmail Inbox, and I don't want it to fetch the images (for tracking protection). I have kept the settings of Don't display images in Gmail Settings option, but it doesn't work for IMAP. Kindly suggest a way out through PHP etc., if its possible.

```
<?php
$server = "{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}INBOX";
$yourEmail = "xyz@gmail.com";
$yourEmailPassword = "abc123";
$mailbox = imap_open($server, $yourEmail, $yourEmailPassword);
$mail = imap_search($mailbox,'SUBJECT "abc"');
$count = count($mail);
echo "<h3>Total number of emails is $count</h3><br>";
rsort($mail);
for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
$mail_headers = imap_headerinfo($mailbox, $mail[$x]);
$to = $mail_headers->toaddress;
#$message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($mailbox,$mail[$x],1));
$message = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($mailbox,$mail[$x],2));
echo "$message<br>";
}
imap_close($mailbox);
?>
```

Comment: Just fetching the email does not fetch external images.  If you wish to display the email, you will need to rewrite the links in the HTML body.

Comment: @Max so if I use preg_match with regex to select plain text parts of the html email and echo the matches instead of the whole message, then the images won't be fetched? That is, my server ip address would be completely protected from any sort of tracking by images?

Comment: regex isn't a great tool for parsing HTML.  Sanitizing HTML is a hard problem; possibly handled in JS with the browser DOM, using an HTML library to find possible external references (img, script, css....).  Email security is a hard problem.